# Dash sign in array key stops printing the actual value

Tags: angularjs

`{{ size_key.['size-0'] }}` won't print the actual value for `size-0`. It comes back as empty. All the other works fine including the ID. Any solution? I tried double quotes as well.

**OBJECT**

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
   $$hashKey: "057"
   id: "53ce8d5e2ac1fb5f00000067"
   size-0: "5"
   size-1: "8"
   __proto__: Object
1: Object
   $$hashKey: "058"
   id: "2h3h34gd5ac1fb5f00000067"
   size-0: "4"
   size-1: "7"
```

**MARKUP**

```
<div ng-repeat="(size_inx, size_key) in design.sizes">
    {{ size_inx }} - {{ size_key.id }} - {{ size_key.['size-0'] }}
</div>
```

Comment: should not it be size_key['size-0']

Comment: Remove the `.`... `size_key.['size-0']`

Comment: Id is acceptable with dot but not the others with dash in it. Weird way of handling things or what! Anyway Thanks guys. +1 to both.

Comment: In javascript, properties can be accessed by dot notation or by associative array notation. So these are equivalent: `obj.prop` and `obj['prop']`